# Making use of the users table, causing an error

Tags: django, django-users

In Django (2.x) I have an entry form, the model is here:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    area_easting = models.IntegerField()
    area_northing = models.IntegerField()
    context_number = models.IntegerField()
    sample_number = models.IntegerField()
    # taken_by = models.IntegerField()
    taken_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.sample_id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'samples\".\"sample'
        #ordering = ["sample_id"]
        managed = False
        #verbose_name_plural = "samples"
```

This works as expected, a list of usernames drops down (while I would like to format - firstname lastname). However, when I return to the main viewing page I see an error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column sample.taken_by_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...text_number", "samples"."sample"."sample_number", "samples"....
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "sample.taken_by".
```

Clearly Django is adding the `_id` to the table name causing the error, I expect because it is a foreign key.

Any ideas how to remedy this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the underlying db column via the `db_column` attribute:

```
taken_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='taken_by', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Currently it shows my name garynobles, I'm assuming in the meta you can do something like firstname + " " + lastname so it displays nicer?

Comment: I presume you're using a form with a ModelChoiceField? You can set the `__str__` method on the target model, or see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) (last paragraph of the section) to customise it further.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

^ link to the docs where it specifies that it creates a `_id` field.

based from the error message you have posted. It seems that your database schema is not updated.

you might need to do manage `makemigrations` and `migrate` to apply your model changes to your db schema

e.g

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
# to apply the new migrations file
$ python manage.py migrate
```